# Program for finding nth root of the number without any external library or header like math.h

Tags: c

Is there any way to find nth root of the number without any external library in C? I'm working on a bare metal code so there is no OS. Also, no complete C is there.

Comment: See: [Nth root algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nth_root_algorithm)

Comment: Integer or float? Do you have hardware division? No complete C makes me curious about your platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a program like this for nth root. This program is for square root.

```
int floorSqrt(int x)
{
    // Base cases
    if (x == 0 || x == 1)
       return x;

    // Staring from 1, try all numbers until
    // i*i is greater than or equal to x.
    int i = 1, result = 1;
    while (result < x)
    {
       if (result == x)
          return result;
       i++;
       result = i*i;
    }
    return i-1;
}
```

You can use the same approach for nth root.

Answer (score 1):

Here there is a C implementation of the the nth root algorithm [you can find in wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nth_root_algorithm). It needs an exponentiation algorithm, so I also include an implementation of a basic method for exponentiation by squaring that [you can find also find in wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring).

```
double npower(double const base, int const n)
{
    if (n < 0) return npower(1/base, -n)
    else if (n == 0) return 1.0;
    else if (n == 1) return base;
    else if (n % 2) return base*npower(base*base, n/2);
    else return npower(base*base, n/2);
}

double nroot(double const base, int const n)
{
    if (n == 1) return base;
    else if (n <= 0 || base < 0) return NAN;
    else {
        double delta, x = base/n;
        do {
            delta = (base/npower(x,n-1)-x)/n;
            x += delta;
        } while (fabs(delta) >= 1e-8);
        return x;
    }
}
```

Some comments on this:

- The nth root algorithm in wikipedia leaves freedom for the initial guess. In this example I set it up to be `base/n`, but this was just a guess.
- The macro `NAN` is usually defined in `<math.h>`, so you would need to define it to be suitable for your needs.
- Both functions are implemented in a very rough and simple way, and their performance can be greatly improved with careful thought.
- The tolerance in this example is set to `1e-8` and should be changed to something different. It should probably be proportional to the value of the base.

Comment: Answer should explain the code, saying why or how it works.

Answer (score -1):

You can try the **nth_root** C function :

```c
// return a number that, when multiplied by itself nth times, makes N.
unsigned nth_root(const unsigned n, const unsigned nth) {
    unsigned a = n, b, c, r = nth ? n + (n > 1) : n == 1 ;
    for (; a < r; b = a + (nth - 1) * r, a = b / nth)
        for (r = a, a = n, c = nth - 1; c && (a /= r); --c);
    return r;
}
```

[Source](https://github.com/michel-leonard/C-MathSnip/blob/main/simple_functions.c)

Comment: Code without explanation is not a good answer.